# adding styles to appending items

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I wasn't sure how to phrase the question, so I guess that's also the reason I couldn't find an answer..

I'm appending elements I create in jQuery. I want to add styles to these elements, but my guess is that the elements don't exist yet, so it won't work. What would be a good way to append these styles? I read something about documentFragments, but I don't understand how they work..

(my first try at a jquery plugin:)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.flPushbox = function(options) {
    settings = $.extend({
        pager: 'true'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        // set local variables  
        var $pushbox = $(this),
        $slides = $(this).children(),
        $viewport = $('<div class="fl-viewport" />'),
        init,
        initPager;

        //wrap ul with viewport
        init = function (){
            $pushbox.wrap($viewport);

            if (settings.pager) initPager();
        }

        initPager = function() {
            var $pager = $('<ul class="fl-pager" />');

            for (i=0; i<$slides.length; i++) {
                var $pagerSlide = $('<li>'+ i +'</li>');
                $pagerSlide.appendTo($pager);
            }

            $pager.insertAfter($pushbox);
        }

        initStyling = function() {
            var pushboxWidth = 0;

            $slides.each(function(index, slide) {                   
                pushboxWidth += parseInt($(slide).outerWidth());
            });

            $viewport.css({
                'position'  : 'relative',
                'overflow'  : 'hidden'
            });

            $slides.css({
                'float' : 'left'

            });

            $pushbox.css({
                'position'  : 'absolute',
                'top'       : 0,
                'left'      : 0,
                'width'     : pushboxWidth
            });
        }

        init();
        initStyling();
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: are you sure you can't? I think I've set properties for things I've created on the fly before I add them to the DOM

Comment: yes I'm sure. The styles for $pushbox are added because it's already in the html file. But the elements I append won't receive any styles

Comment: Oh I have to correct that the slides do receive their styles (float:left), but $viewport doesnt

Comment: I think the problem is that when you do the `.wrap`, $viewport still references the 'temporary' element, not the ones inserted in the function `init`. Try doing a `$viewport=$pushbox.find(".fl-viewport")`  (for example) before assigning `$viewport.css` in initStyling

Comment: ahh, that's it! now I just reference to $('.viewport') instead of the element I created ($viewport). Jeesh, sometimes the solution can be so simple, thanks a lot @Rodolfo ! :)